# QTableWidget and QLineEdit - position and text content

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit, qcompleter

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the position(column and row) and the content in the QLineEdit. I'm using a eventFilter to get the signal but from there i'm stuck. any advice? Thank you

```
 ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(5);
 ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);

 QStringList wordList;
 wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omega2" << "omega3" <<"omicron" << "zeta";

 for(int i = 0; i<5;i++)
 {

 QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit;

 QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList);
 completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
 lineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
 lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
 ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,i,lineEdit);
 }

 ....

 bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject * object, QEvent *event)
 {

  }
```

I would like to get the position when I finish editing. I would like to pick a word from the list either through up and down key or left mouse click. Once a word is picked that word would populate the QLineEdit. Then i would want to know the position. Now, if the user writes a text different from the content of the list then no position should be returned. I'm only interested on whats in the "wordList". Thank you

Comment: When do you want to get the row and column, when you finish editing?

Comment: Eyllanesc: Yes, I would like to get the position when I finish editing. I would like to pick a word from the list either through up and down key or left mouse click. Once a word is picked that word would populate the QLineEdit. Then i would want to know the position. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicate in your comments, you only want to obtain the text when an element that is set in the `QCompleter` is selected, for this we must use the `void QCompleter::activated(const QString & text)` signal.

To do this, a slot is created and the connection is made:

***.h**

```
private slots:
    void onActivated(const QString &text);
```

***.cpp**

```
    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList);
    ...
    connect(completer, qOverload<const QString &>(&QCompleter::activated), this, &MainWindow::onActivated);
```

There are 2 possible solutions:

- The first to use the position of the `QLineEdit` that we obtain through the `widget()` method of the `QCompleter`, and the `QCompleter` we obtain it through `sender()` which is the object that emits the signal and `pos()`. then we get the `QModelIndex` with `indexAt()`, and this has the information of the row and column:

---

```
void MainWindow::onActivated(const QString &text)
{
    QCompleter *completer = static_cast<QCompleter *>(sender());
    QModelIndex ix = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(completer->widget()->pos());
    if(ix.isValid()){
        qDebug()<<ix.row()<<ix.column()<<text;
    }
}
```

- Or the row and column is saved as a property:

---

```
    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList);
    ...
    completer->setProperty("row", i);
    completer->setProperty("column", i);

void MainWindow::onActivated(const QString &text)
{
    QCompleter *completer = static_cast<QCompleter *>(sender());
    qDebug()<< completer->property("row").toInt()<<completer->property("column").toInt()<<text;    
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49353042) you can find both complete examples

Comment: Eyllanesc: Yes, I would like to get the position when I finish editing. I would like to pick a word from the list either through up and down key or left mouse click. Once a word is picked that word would populate the QLineEdit. Then i would want to know the position. Thank you

Comment: @VMI and what happens if the user writes a text different from the content of the list, should he also indicate the position?

Comment: if the user writes a text different from the content of the list then no position should be returned. I'm only interested on whats on the list.

Comment: @VMI Edit your question and specify it.